# Get the object value from the unknown index loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the search result from the data . Every time my search result index is different.

one time result will coming in 4th index and next time result will come in 100th index.

how to get rank value inside the dataResult

```
dataResult:
127: { lastName: "rahul",firstName: "rahul",rank:"3"   }


 dataResult:
3: { lastName: "rahul",firstName: "rahul",rank:"3"   }

dataResult:
4: { lastName: "rahul",firstName: "rahul",rank:"3"   }

dataResult:
87: { lastName: "rahul",firstName: "rahul",rank:"3"   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get rank"? Can you post valid Javascript / JSON and an example of the code you have?

Comment: Well you can sort the list based on firstname /lastname first and then access the element, this way the position will always be same

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` like that

```
Object.values(dataResult).rank
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for in loop to iterate through the values

```
for (let key in dataResult) {
  console.log(key); // should give you index number i.e 4 or 100
  console.log(dataResult[key]); // should display the object on the console
  console.log(dataResult[key].rank); // you should see the rank value
}
```

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataList.find(result => result.firstName === 'rahul').rank
```

change the condition according to your search query